# Watir : NoMethodError: undefined method `click' for nil:NilClass

Tags: watir

I'm trying to expand a dynamic section of the UI without much success. It works like a charm in the console (using the rubyshell instance) but when I execute this in a batch on TestWise I get this error:

```
NoMethodError:
undefined method `click' for nil:NilClass
```

Could you please have a look and maybe through some ideas?

HTML

```
<div id="ID1">
   <div id="ID2" class="CLASS1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <div class="CLASS2" onclick="some javascript goes here">
        <span class="CLASS3">Some text goes here</span>
    <div id="ID3" class="CLASS4"></div>
</div>
```

And the Watir code:

```
@browser.div(:id, "ID1").div(:id, ID2).span(:class, "CLASS3").click
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the error message says that `span(:class, "CLASS3")` returns `nil`.

If the code works in IRB but not when you run the script, it is usually timing problem. Maybe the element is not at the page when you try to access it.

By the way, `div(:id, ID2)` should be `div(:id, "ID2")` (please notice the quotes), otherwise it should raise `NameError: uninitialized constant ID2` (assuming that you did not define constant `ID2` any you want to access `<div id="ID2">`.